# C if statement not recognising scan input

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, equals-operator

So I'm trying to make a simple temperature converter. All looks fine to me but I don't know why the scan input is not being recognised.
Thanks for your time.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    exercise1(){
        float a;
        char tem;
        printf("--- Temperature Converter ---\n");
        printf("Please enter a temperature: ");
        scanf("%f", &a);
        printf("\nWould you like to convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit? (c or f)");
        scanf("%c", &tem); getchar();
        if (tem == 'c'){
            a = ((float)a-32) * 5.0f/9.0f;
            printf("\nYour temperature is %g\n", &a);
        }
        else if (tem == 'f'){
            a = (float)a * 9.0f/5.0f + 32;
            printf("\nYour temperature is %g\n", &a);
        }
        else
            printf("\nPlease enter a valid conversion type!\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `printf("\nYour temperature is %g\n", &a);` remove `&` --> `printf("\nYour temperature is %g\n", a);`

Comment: Probably because you are calling `getchar` right after it. By the way, with `float a`, there is no need for `(float)a` later in the code (but that is purely semantic).

Comment: Thanks, I combined all of the answers and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the scanf() was when you entered a whitespace to finish inserting the temperature, that whitespace would then be inserted to tem.
In order to prevent it, use the getchar() before the scanf(), as shown below.

**NOTE:** when checking the answers given to you, I saw one suggesting you use " %c" instead of "%c". This is a good idea, and it works well. Note that if you prefer this solution, you should not use getchar()

In addition, there were few more mistakes that I found:
1. When using printf(), you should not send &a, but send a instead. printf() does not require a pointer, but a variable. (Notice the warning while compiling)
2. Use %f to scan floats, not %g
3. You have used too much } after the last else (only one is needed, to close the function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
        float a;
        char tem;
        printf("--- Temperature Converter ---\n");
        printf("Please enter a temperature: ");
        scanf("%f", &a);
        printf("\nWould you like to convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit? (c or f)");
        getchar();
        scanf("%c", &tem);
        if (tem == 'c'){
                a = ((float)a-32) * 5.0f/9.0f;
                printf("\nYour temperature is %f\n", a);
        }
        else if (tem == 'f'){
                a = (float)a * 9.0f/5.0f + 32;
                printf("\nYour temperature is %f\n", a);
        }
        else
                printf("\nPlease enter a valid conversion type!\n");}
```